# Webgoat missing function level access control lesson

Tags: web-application, java, access-control, webgoat

I've recently installed WebGoat 8.00M12 on my computer and I tried to solve the "Access Control" section for a demonstration in my class.

Everything was simple and smooth till I got stuck at the last point in "Missing function level access control lesson" subsection, and I got stuck there for 2 full days now. Can anyone help me, please?

The question is this:

[image: Question]

**Note:** the previous page contained 2 CSS hidden hyperlinks (/users and /config) that doesn't work when i click on them or try them (These are supposedly only available for the admin)

**What I have done:**

- Using burp suite to spider the web application the intended directories where not found.
- Tried many combinations like (show-users users list-users display-users) on many directories but just couldn't find the "users page" they talked about in the hints, but I did found some useless page at /WebGoat/users which contained only "su 1" just FYI.

**Helpful notes:**

- The WebApplication runs a RESTful structure.
- It runs on Java (I tried reading the source code on github but didn't understand anything).
- Download WebGoat v8.0 (if you care) [Here](https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat/releases/download/v8.0.0.M12/webgoat-server-8.0.0.M12.jar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its kind of a hard challenge.

First when you click on the human symbol to logout you should notice there is a role: **User.**

Also when you visit /users you should notice in the source code a hidden button like **"admin"** or something like that. So you need to try somehow change the role.

Logout and try to register again. Notice the post parameters.

So do the same on /users but with:

parameters in a list --

> {"parameter1":"value", etc }

add a new parameter role

> ( value: Admin wont work so try WebGoat_Admin)

and also change

> content-type:application/json

Comment: Thank you, although this is definitely a bit late xD i already solved the challenge similar to the way you described it